# Is it thread safe when 2 threads modifies different member of a class object concurrently?

Tags: multithreading, locking

If thread1 and thread2 execute concurrently without locks, will class A be thread safe.

```
class A{
private:
   Data data_;
   next ptr_;
};
A a = new A();
thread1:
  A obj1 = a;
  obj1.data_ = 5;
thread2:
  A obj2 = a;
  obj2.ptr_ = another;
```

Comment: Depends what you mean by thread-safe.

Comment: @shmosel If class A is queue node, enqueue will modify ptr_ to next node, dequeue will modify data_ to null.

Comment: which language is it?

Comment: you are not sharing the object (`obj1` or `obj2`) among different threads, so it should be thread safe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. As you mentioned, when the object is queue node, by enqueuing and dequeuing, two threads won't conflict, if they access the node member respectively.

Comment: Suppose that the only item in queue is node(the instance of ur class A), which is pointed by both head pointer and tail pointer. Tail pointer will set node->next to added element and head pointer will get node->data, set node->data to null and set tail to null. It is thread safe.